# Upload files to AWS S3 with plain Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

I'm trying to list the files in the bucket named `0-test` on S3 using the `aws-sdk` gem. This is my code:

```
require require 'aws-sdk'

Aws.config.update({
  region: 'Ireland',
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(key, key2)
})

s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new
print s3.list_buckets
```

This is the (important part of the) error I get:

```
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize': unable to connect to `s3.ireland.amazonaws.com`; SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError)
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your region name is incorrect. While that region is colloquially known as Ireland, the API name is `eu-west-1`. There is a full list of regions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html)